# Android Studio: Image appears in IDE and Emulator, not copied to device

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

## The problem

I'm developing a test app to gain some confidence with Android Studio. I have created a single-activity app with a countdown timer and a PNG image of a toothbrush.

## Code

```
package com.ecam.myapplication2;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeRemainingText);
        final ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final ProgressBar pBar2 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        final ImageView toothbrushImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final long maxTime = 2 * 6 * 1000;
        final long steps = 10;
        new CountDownTimer(maxTime, steps) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long minutesRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 1000 / 60;
                long secondsRemaining = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                long centisecondsRemaining = (millisUntilFinished / 10) % 100;
                float percentCompleted = 100 - (((float)millisUntilFinished) / maxTime) * 100;
                //float msFloat = (float) millisUntilFinished;
                //int progress = (int)(msFloat/maxTime*100);
                //mTextField.setText(progress+"seconds remaining: " + String.format("%.2f", msFloat / 1000));
                mTextField.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d.%02d", minutesRemaining, secondsRemaining, centisecondsRemaining));
                pBar.setProgress((int)percentCompleted);
                pBar2.setProgress(100-(int)percentCompleted);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mTextField.setText("done!");
                pBar.setProgress(100);
                pBar2.setProgress(0);
            }
        }.start();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/time_remaining_title"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ff5611ff"
                android:textSize="45dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:id="@+id/timeRemainingText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="308dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:max="100"
                android:indeterminate="false" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="308dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                android:max="100"
                android:indeterminate="false"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="308dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/toothbrush"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it is well displayed both on the IDE and on an emulator:

[image]

But it does not appear on my device (Nexus 5):

[image]

**Any idea whys the image is not copied or displayed on my device?**

## What I've tried (thanks for the comments!)

- `adjustViewBounds=true`
- Using background instead of src, or both background and src
- Restarting the IDE
- Installing from an APK

Comment: Maybe adjustViewBounds=true; or use background instead of src... idk though really. I've had issues with Lollipop myself.

Comment: @scubasteve623 Thanks! Tried both, didn't help.

Comment: Can you add your activity layout XML (not just the ImageView excerpt) please? Are you modifying any of the views/layout in code, apart from `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`?

Comment: @ataulm Done. The code is pretty slim (it's a test app), and I don't change anything except for the progressbar.

Comment: Can you try the ImageView with only `layout_width`, `layout_height` and `src`? I can't see anything in the layout that would affect the visibility of the ImageView (though there are many ignored layout attributes because of the type of parent - these won't affect the visibility of the view though).

Comment: Try running **`uiautomatorviewer`** and see what it tells you about that `ImageView`.

Comment: Same problem, have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a smaller size of your image, I had the exact same problem and it worked for me.